# "Session Failed - probably due to lack of camera access" Xcode Error

Tags: swift, arkit

I followed this tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/378-augmented-reality-and-arkit-tutorial to learn about Augmented Reality.

when I run the project I get the error :

```
 Session did fail with error: Error Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=100 "Unsupported configuration." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unsupported configuration., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The provided configuration is not supported on this device.} Session Failed - probably due to lack of camera access.
```

I didn't find the cause of this error even I make a test to verify that the simulator support ARKit using the following code :

```
 if (ARConfiguration.isSupported) {
 print("ARKit is supported. You can work with ARKit")
  } else {
    print("ARKit is not supported. You cannot work with ARKit")
  }
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Probably the fact that you're running your app on simulator

Comment: Is not possible de run apps with Augmented Reality on Simulator ?

Comment: Oh, you actually can run your app on simulator, but it won't work how you're expecting. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if ARConfiguration.isSupported {
>     print("ARKit is supported. You can work with ARKit")
> } else {
>     print("ARKit is not supported. You cannot work with ARKit")
> }
> ```

this `ARConfiguration.isSupported` doesn't actually indicate if device (or simulator) where you're running your app is able to work with world tracking or something similar (which is required for lot of AR features).

You may want to check if some of [`ARConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration) subclasses is supported... for example this [`ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration)

```
if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported { ... }
```

---

Anyway, this doesn't solve problem with getting your error and if you want to test your AR apps, you will have to run your app **on real device.**